# After selecting value from autocomplete suggestions, fill in the rest of the fields based on the selected value

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

So i have a autocomplete in one of my views, that is working, now i want to add a feature where users searches for product writtes in some key words finds it and selects it, when the name of the product is selected i want to dynamically fill in price for that product, the info is in the database, how can I achieve this?

My JQuery for autocomplete

```
$(function(){
    var controller_path = document.getElementById("get_controller_path").value;
    $("#product").autocomplete({
        source: controller_path
    });
});
```

My view where i want dynamically the price to popup when autocomplete suggestion is selected:

```
<td><input type="text" id="product" name="prodname"></td>
<input type="hidden" id="get_controller_path" value="<?echo base_url().'admin_site_offers_ctrl/get_product';?>">
<td><input style="width: 60px" type="text" name="price" id="price"></td>
```

Controller for autocomplete

```
  public function get_product(){
    $this->load->model('offers_for_clients_model');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
        $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $this->offers_for_clients_model->get_product($q);
    }
}
```

Model for that autocomplete functionality:

```
function get_product($q){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->like('nosauk_lv', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('produkti');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $row_set[] = htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['nosauk_lv'])); //build an array
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
    }
}
```

How should i approach this? Any pointers to right direction would be amazing! Thanks! 
P.S The autocomplete is wokring no worries about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply this worked for me ended up doing this:

```
 $(function(){
    var controller_path = document.getElementById("get_controller_path").value;
    $("#product").autocomplete({
        source: controller_path, // ceļš uz kontrolieri kur atrodas metode, admin_site_offers_ctrl
        select: function(a,b){
            $(this).val(b.item.value); //grabed the selected value
            getProductsOtherInfo(b.item.value);//passed that selected value
        }
    });
});
```

Other function made request to database based on the selected values name
and loaded them in the appropriate fields that i needed, like this:

```
function getProductsOtherInfo(name){
var site_url = document.getElementById('get_products_other_info').value;
/*alert(site_url);*/
        $.post(site_url, {
            name : name,
            site_url : site_url
        },

        function(rawdata){
            var myObject = JSON.parse(rawdata);
            $('#cena_pirms_atl').val(myObject[0].cena_ls);
            $('#iepcena').html(myObject[0].ped_ien_ls);
            $('#nom_id').val(myObject[0].ID);
            getPZtotals();
        });
    }
```

The controller:

```
function get_products_other_info(){
    $this->load->model('offers_for_clients_model');
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);

    $data['products_other_info'] = $this->offers_for_clients_model->get_products_other_info($name);
    echo json_encode($data['products_other_info']);
}
```

The model:

```
function get_products_other_info($name){
    $decode_name = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($name));
    $query = $this->db->where('nosauk_lv', $decode_name)->get('produkti')->result();
    return $query;
}
```

View:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="nom_id" id="nom_id">
  <td><input style="width: 60px" type="text" name="cena_pirms_atl"  id="cena_pirms_atl"></td>
  <td id="iepirkcens"><span id="iepcena"></span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
    $("#product").autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: customurl,
                        data: {term: request.term},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function( data ) {
                            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                               // you can set the label value
                          return {
                                label: item.value,
                                value: item.value,
                            }
                           }
                        }));
                     }
                 });
           },
        select: function( event, ui ) 
            {
        // Here again you can call ajax function to get the product price
        var prodname=$('#prodname').val(ui.prodid);
        getproductprice(prodname);
            },
         change: function( event, ui )
          {
            var prodname=$('#prodname').val(ui.prodid);
            getproductprice(prodname);
          }
        });
```

Please make sure in your model get the id of product also in `$row_set[]`.

In `html` declare like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="prodname" id="prodname"> // Here you will get product name id after select the productname
```

In `getproductprice` function you can call the ajax function to get the price

```
function getproductprice(prodname)
{
    if(prodname>0)
    {
        $.ajax({
           url:customurl,
           data: "prodid="+prodname,
           dataType: "json",
           success: function( data ) {
             $('#price').val(data['price']); // whatever your varaible
           }

         });

     }
}
```

I think this will help to solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: trying to implement your solution, will come back to you when finished or some errors ocure, dont worry you can up vote my question, i will come back to you in a bit! :)

Comment: Question, whats the right way to add the ID variable to that row_set, im currently struggling with that, thanks!

Comment: @BenDover.. In `for loop` you added this line ` $row_set[] = htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['nosauk_lv']));`. below that same like `$row_set[]=$row['prodid']`. becoz `row_set` is array.